# Need Specific Background Images for each ul tag

Tags: css

I am learning CSS these days..

Iam using Nested ul li , Could you please tell how to achieve same background image specific to each Ul? Below is the code:

```
<ul class="display_BG_Blue_arw">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul class="display_BG_Red_arw">
    <li>Black tea</li>
    <li>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

where class="display_BG_Blue" --> each li of that ul tag should display background Image as Blue Arrow  &&

class="display_BG_Red_arw" --> each li of that ul tag should display background Image as Red Arrow

BTW, where can I find easily small-sized backgound images for these things..?

Comment: The first part of the question 'how do I..?' I've answered (or tried) below, the second part really is something I think you'd have to Google. I'd suggest searching for free, and possibly Creative Commons-licensed/open source, images. Flickr is often quite good (just remember to check the permissions attached to the files, to be sure of not opening yourself up to copyright-infringement law-suit, or such-like).

Answer (score 1):

Select the `li` elements based on their parent:

```
.display_BG_Blue_arw > li {
    background-image: url(/path/to/blue_arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* or whatever... */
    background-position: 0 50%; /* or whatever... */
}

.display_BG_Red_arw > li {
    background-image: url(/path/to/red_arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* or whatever... */
    background-position: 0 50%; /* or whatever... */
}
```

The use of the `>` combinator is to specify that only those `li` elements that are immediate descendants/children of the `.display_BG_Red_arw` will be styled with the red arrow, to prevent `li` elements in nested `ul`/`ol` elements being styled with the same background.

References:

- [CSS (Level 3) Combinators, at the W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators).
- [CSS (Level 3) Selectors, at the W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.display_BG_Blue_arw > li{
  background-image: url(/path/to/blue_arrow.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* or whatever... */
  background-position: 0 50%; /* or whatever... */
}

ul > li ul.display_BG_Blue_arw li{
  background-image: url(/path/to/blue_arrow.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* or whatever... */
  background-position: 0 50%; /* or whatever... */
}
```

or

```
ul > li ul li{
  background-image: url(/path/to/blue_arrow.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* or whatever... */
  background-position: 0 50%; /* or whatever... */
}
```